# Ruby on rails , two views in a controller show the same output but have different html code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a simple ruby on rails app. It has a controller name ControllerB which has 4 views namely index, show, edit and new.

show.html.erb in the views folder contains the html code:

```
<p>Show post</p>
```

edit.html.erb contains:

```
<p>Edit post</p>
```

And this is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  

    get 'controller_a/myindex'
    resources :post_controller
    resources :controller_b
    root 'controller_a#myindex'

end
```

The problem is, when I try to open the edit view using the url http://localhost:3000/controller_b/edit
It shows the contents of show view i.e. Show post.

But when I remove the line resources :controller_b from routes.rb and import each view using the get command, it works fine. What is going wrong here? I also restarted the rails webrick server to make sure that the new configurations have been loaded.

This is my controller_b_controller.rb file:

```
class ControllerBController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def edit
  end

  def new
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

As requested by Prashanth, this is my rake route output.

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              
Controller#Action
controller_b_index GET    /controller_b/index(.:format)           
controller_b#index
controller_a_myindex GET    /controller_a/myindex(.:format)      
controller_a#myindex
post_controller_index GET    /post_controller(.:format)              
post_controller#index
                      POST   /post_controller(.:format)             
post_controller#create
new_post_controller GET    /post_controller/new(.:format)        
post_controller#new
edit_post_controller GET    /post_controller/:id/edit(.:format)   
post_controller#edit
  post_controller GET    /post_controller/:id(.:format)      post_controller#show
                  PATCH  /post_controller/:id(.:format)      post_controller#update
                  PUT    /post_controller/:id(.:format)      post_controller#update
                  DELETE /post_controller/:id(.:format)      post_controller#destroy
                  GET    /controller_b(.:format)             controller_b#index
                  POST   /controller_b(.:format)             controller_b#create
 new_controller_b GET    /controller_b/new(.:format)         controller_b#new
edit_controller_b GET    /controller_b/:id/edit(.:format)    controller_b#edit
     controller_b GET    /controller_b/:id(.:format)         controller_b#show
                  PATCH  /controller_b/:id(.:format)         controller_b#update
                  PUT    /controller_b/:id(.:format)         controller_b#update
                  DELETE /controller_b/:id(.:format)         controller_b#destroy
             root GET    /                                   controller_a#myindex
```

Comment: Is this your actual code, or do you have some more stuff you think are not relevent? This usually happens when rails treats `edit` as it was an `:id`, however code you've posted should not cause that.

Comment: @BroiSatse Are you talking about routes.rb? Then yes, this is it. And also, yes both edit.html.erb and show.html.erb have only this much code, a paragraph tag.

Comment: Anything interesting within a controller then?

Comment: Show the `rake routes` output @AdityaNaidu

Comment: @Prashant4020 I edited my question and added the rake routes output.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why is the :id added to the url??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the same thing is because the `show` path expects a url with this formatting:

```
controller_b GET    /controller_b/:id
```

So when you go to either `/controller_b/show` or `/controller_b/edit`, it thinks the `:id` is `show` and `edit` respectively.

---

If you want a singular resource route, you have to change your route definition to:

```
resource :controller_b
```

which will give you access to this route:

```
controller_b GET    /controller_b
```

No `show` required, in fact I think it might just fail if you specify anything other than `edit` or `new`.

Comment: Thanks! But what is the purpose of adding :id to the url?

Comment: That's how `resources` routes work. `show` is to display a single item view hence you need to tell the controller which item you're looking at. You might want to look into singular resources: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Answer (score 4):

Your `edit` url should be look like:

```
http://localhost:3000/controller_b/:id/edit
```

Comment: `:id` is the object id